# After changed datatype from gdal.GDT_UInt32 to gdal.GDT_Byte, I had GDALDataset::GetRasterBand(2) - Illegal band #

Tags: gdal, digital-image-processing

I have several UAV images with 4 bands, and I wanna merge them. The data type of these images are all UInt8. I tried to use following code to store my merged numpy.

```
dataset = driver.Create(path, Raster.shape[2], Raster.shape[1], gdal.GDT_Byte, options=["COMPRESS=LZW"])
if dataset is not None:
    dataset.SetGeoTransform(new_geotrans)
    dataset.SetProjection(raster_proj)
    for i in range(bands):
        dataset.GetRasterBand(i + 1).WriteArray(fullRaster[i, :, :])
```

I got this error
`GDALDataset::GetRasterBand(2) - Illegal band #`
It is weird because gdal.GDT_Byte is equal to UInt 8 I think.
Then, I tried to change gdal.GDT_Byte to gdal.GDT_UInt16. I got this error.
`GDALDataset::GetRasterBand(3) - Illegal band #` Same error but occurs in a different band.
After this, I changed gdal.GDT_UInt16 to gdal.GDT_UInt32. It works.

Can someone tell me why I cannot use gdal.GDT_Byte given the data type of UAV images is UInt8? Why  does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Driver-class.html), the signature is:

`Driver.Create(path, xsize, ysize, bands, eType, options)`

You seem to be feeding in a datatype as the `bands` argument.  GDAL datatypes are represented using an enumeration, so the behavior you're seeing makes sense given the incorrect ordering.

Comment: You're right!! Thanks!! But it's weird why it works even I fed in a UInt32 as the bands argument. And I also didn't get what do you mean by "enumeration" in this context.

Comment: Nice.  Enumeration meaning that the datatypes you import are actually just variables that each hold a unique integer, and those integers represent the dtype internally to the rest of gdal.  [If you look here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gcore/gdal.h#L63-L80) you'll see that  treating the variable `gdal.GDT_UInt32` as a number is equivalent to just using the integer `4`

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation!!